# Doxygen for Lua

Tags: lua, doxygen

I am trying to get [lua2dox](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lua2dox) running but it's not generating the examples.

What I do is [download the zip file](http://mirrors.ctan.org/web/lua2dox.zip) and [download doxygen 1.8.8](https://sourceforge.net/projects/doxygen/files/snapshots/doxygen-1.8-svn/windows/). I'll then place the `doxygen.exe` file into the extracted content od lua2dox and simply call

```
> doxygen.exe
```

in my command line. The `docs/` directory is getting created but it does not look like the [example docs](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/web/lua2dox/examples/lua) as it is shown e.g. [here](http://mirror.easyname.at/ctan/web/lua2dox/examples/lua/docs/html/classAnimal.html).

The generated documentation has just the list of files - and that's it.

I've checked the `Doxygen` file but I can't find anything that seems to be wrong.

What I am not sure about is if `lua2dox_filter.bat` is actually getting used by doxygen. As I run it, I do not see some output from this script, not even if I add some `echo` but maybe it's just doxygen itself suppressing it.

---

**Two things:** The only modification I had to make was to `lua2dox_filter.bat`. In order to run Lua it has to prompt `lua5.1` instead of just `lua` as it is in the script.

Also the `Doxyfile` didn't point to the `examples/lua` directory so I hat to set it:

```
INPUT                  = examples/lua/
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Answer:** Don't use Doxygen 1.8.8.

I didn't test it with later versions but it worked with Doxygen v1.8.2. Apparently things broke later on for lua2dox.

Comment: Quick guess did you look at EXTENSION_MAPPING ?

Comment: @albert No, I'd have to check - could this be the reason it didn' work with 1.8.8?

Comment: Depending on the used extension this might be the case.

Comment: I was looking through some doxygen issues, in particular https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/6296, so I was wondering: - is the lua2dox prject dead? - did you do some tests with `EXTENSION_MAPPING`?